# CSS table border corner and inner vertical border

Tags: css

I would like to create a table with style like this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLL9g.png

Could you please help me ?

Thanks and best regards;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Where's your HTML and CSS? Please read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See CSS3's rounded corners at W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp